# Should I escape numbers in Django?

Tags: xss

Should I escape numbers in django to prevent XSS attacks ?
The numbers are stored in db and of "decimal,float,..." type.
Should I escape these values or is it useless to prevent XSS attacks ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would be able to do XSS based purely on numeric values. However a good approach is to always escape input variables and check them for type. For instance if a user is required to input a number, he might also insert a string which could cause an exception in your program. This is something you need to take into account. Note that client side validation is useless (so checking with JavaScript or a dropdown list with only numbers is not going to help you perform secure input validation).

So in Python you can do:

```
   try:
       float(variable)
       "do database logic"
   except:
       print "not valid."
```

Comment: are python and django type validation enough ?

Comment: Beware, input such as "NaN" and "Infinity" will pass this test. If the input is used in flow control, "NaN" has some nasty surprises. I have no idea how a database will react to such input.